# require user input as arabic language in form field in laravel and vue.js 2 application

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have tried first google translation in larvel [   

Full Name الاسم الكامل
(Required)

 -->
<input type="text" class="form-control" dir="rtl" v-model="text1" @keyup="arabicValue( text1)" id= "text1">

```
 arabicValue: function(txt,text1) {
   console.log(txt + "txt");
    let char;
    // char = txt.value;
    char = txt;
    console.log(char  + "in");
    char = char.replace(/`/g, "ذ");
    char = char.replace(/0/g, "۰");
    char = char.replace(/1/g, "۱");
    char = char.replace(/2/g, "۲");
    char = char.replace(/3/g, "۳");
    char = char.replace(/4/g, "٤");
    char = char.replace(/5/g, "۵");
    char = char.replace(/6/g, "٦");
    char = char.replace(/7/g, "۷");
    char = char.replace(/8/g, "۸");
    char = char.replace(/9/g, "۹");
    char = char.replace(/0/g, "۰");
    char  = char.replace(/q/g, "ف");
    char  = char.replace(/w/g, "ث");
    char  = char.replace(/e/g, "ه");
    char  = char.replace(/r/g, "ص");
    char  = char.replace(/t/g, "ط"); 
    char  = char.replace(/y/g, "ذ");
    char  = char.replace(/u/g, "ش");
    char  = char.replace(/i/g, "أنا");
    char  = char.replace(/o/g, "ا");
    char  = char.replace(/p/g, "ص");
    char  = char.replace(/\[/g, "ج");
    char  = char.replace(/\]/g, "د");
    char  = char.replace(/a/g, "أ");
    char  = char.replace(/s/g, "س");
    char  = char.replace(/d/g, "د");
    char  = char.replace(/f/g, "ب");
    char  = char.replace(/g/g, "ز");
    char  = char.replace(/h/g, "ح");
    char  = char.replace(/j/g, "ي");
    char  = char.replace(/k/g, "ك");
    char  = char.replace(/l/g, "ل");
    char = char.replace(/\;/g, "ك");
    char  = char.replace(/\'/g, "ط");
    char  = char.replace(/z/g, "ض");
    char  = char.replace(/x/g, "ء");
    char  = char.replace(/c/g, "ج");
    char  = char.replace(/v/g, "الخامس");
    char  = char.replace(/b/g, "ب");
    char  = char.replace(/n/g, "ن");
    char  = char.replace(/m/g, "م");
    char  = char.replace(/\,/g, "و");
    char  = char.replace(/\./g, "ز");
    char  = char.replace(/\//g, "ظ");
    char  = char.replace(/~/g, " ّ");
    char  = char.replace(/Q/g, "َ");
    char  = char.replace(/W/g, "ً");
    char  = char.replace(/E/g, "ُ");
    char  = char.replace(/R/g, "ٌ");
    char  = char.replace(/T/g, "ط");
    char  = char.replace(/Y/g, "إ");
    char  = char.replace(/U/g, "‘");
    char  = char.replace(/I/g, "÷");
    char  = char.replace(/O/g, "×");
    char  = char.replace(/P/g, "؛");
    char  = char.replace(/A/g, "ِ");
    char  = char.replace(/S/g, "ٍ");
    char  = char.replace(/G/g, "لأ");
    // char  = char.replace(/H/g, "أ");
    char  = char.replace(/J/g, "ـ");
    char  = char.replace(/K/g, "،");
    char  = char.replace(/L/g, "/");
    char  = char.replace(/Z/g, "~");
    char  = char.replace(/X/g, "ْ");
    char  = char.replace(/B/g, "لآ");
    char  = char.replace(/N/g, "آ");
    char  = char.replace(/M/g, "’");
    char  = char.replace(/\?/g, "؟");
    text1 = char;
    this.text1 =  text1;
     console.log(text1 + "after");
    }`enter code here`
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7AvM.png)and then also tried char replacement in arabic from english on user input and  problem is there is no right conversion from english to arabic.is there any way to get exact right arabic characters on user input.

Answer (score 0):

```
PHP:
For Numbers:
$inputNumbers = $numbers;
$arabic_numbers = ['٩', '٨', '٧', '٦', '٥', '٤', '٣', '٢', '١','٠'];
$num = range(0, 9);
$arabic_numbers_output = str_replace($arabic_numbers , $num, $inputNumbers);

For Letters:
$inputText = $text;
$arabic_letters = ['آ', 'ب', 'ج']; // and so on ...
$letters = ['A', 'B', 'J']; // and so on ...
$arabic_letters_output = str_replace($arabic_letters , $letters , $inputText);


JS:
For Numbers:
    String.prototype.toArabicDigit= function()
{ 
var id= ['۰','۱','۲','۳','۴','۵','۶','۷','۸','۹']; 
return this.replace(/[0-9]/g, function(w){ return id[+w] });
 }
    
    var en_number = "0123456789"; 
    alert(en_number.toArabicDigit());
```

For Letters:
(This is for Farsi but you can modify it to match with Arabic)

```
if (typeof HTMLElement!="undefined" && ! HTMLElement.prototype.insertAdjacentElement) {
    HTMLElement.prototype.insertAdjacentElement = function (where,parsedNode) {
        switch (where) {
            case 'beforeBegin':
                this.parentNode.insertBefore(parsedNode,this)
                break;
            case 'afterBegin':
                this.insertBefore(parsedNode,this.firstChild);
                break;
            case 'beforeEnd':
                this.appendChild(parsedNode);
                break;
            case 'afterEnd':
                if (this.nextSibling)
                    this.parentNode.insertBefore(parsedNode,this.nextSibling);
                else
                    this.parentNode.appendChild(parsedNode);
                break;
        }
    }

    HTMLElement.prototype.insertAdjacentHTML = function (where,htmlStr) {
        var r = this.ownerDocument.createRange();
        r.setStartBefore(this);
        var parsedHTML = r.createContextualFragment(htmlStr);
        this.insertAdjacentElement(where,parsedHTML)
    }

    HTMLElement.prototype.insertAdjacentText = function (where,txtStr) {
        var parsedText = document.createTextNode(txtStr)
        this.insertAdjacentElement(where,parsedText)
    }
}

var FarsiType = {
    // Farsi keyboard map based on Iran Popular Keyboard Layout
    farsiKey: [
        32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 1548,   1711,
        41, 40, 215,    43, 1608,   45, 46, 47,
        48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55,
        56, 57, 58, 1705,   44, 61, 46, 1567,
        64, 1616,   1584,   125,    1609,   1615,   1609,   1604,
        1570,   247,    1600,   1548,   47, 8217,   1583,   215,
        1563,   1614,   1569,   1613,   1601,   8216,   123,    1611,
        1618,   1573,   126,    1580,   1688,   1670,   94, 95,
        1662,   1588,   1584,   1586,   1740,   1579,   1576,   1604,
        1575,   1607,   1578,   1606,   1605,   1574,   1583,   1582,
        1581,   1590,   1602,   1587,   1601,   1593,   1585,   1589,
        1591,   1594,   1592,   60, 124,    62, 1617
    ],
    Type: true,
    counter: 0,
    ShowChangeLangButton: 1,    // 0: Hidden / 1: Visible
    KeyBoardError: 0,           // 0: Disable FarsiType / 1: Show Error
    ChangeDir: 2,           // 0: No Action / 1: Do Rtl-Ltr / 2: Rtl-Ltr button
    UnSupportedAction: 0        //0: Disable FarsiType / 1: Low Support
}

FarsiType.enable_disable = function(Dis) {
    var invis, obj;
    
    if (!Dis.checked)  {
        FarsiType.Type = true;
        disable = false;
        color = 'darkblue';
    } else {
        FarsiType.Type = false;
        disable = true;
        color = '#ECE9D8';
    }

    if (FarsiType.ShowChangeLangButton == 1) { 
        for (var i=1; i<= FarsiType.counter; i++) {
            obj = document.getElementById('FarsiType_button_' + i);
            obj.disabled = disable;
            obj.style.backgroundColor = color;
        }
    }
}

FarsiType.Disable = function() {
    FarsiType.Type = false;
    var Dis = document.getElementById('disableFarsiType')
    if (Dis != null) {
        Dis.checked = true;
    }

    if (FarsiType.ShowChangeLangButton == 1) { 
        for (var i=1; i<= FarsiType.counter; i++) {
            obj = document.getElementById('FarsiType_button_' + i);
            obj.disabled = true;
            obj.style.backgroundColor = '#ECE9D8';
        }
    }
}

FarsiType.init = function() {

    var Inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT');
    for (var i=0; i<Inputs.length; i++) {
        if (Inputs[i].type.toLowerCase() == 'text' && (Inputs[i].lang.toLowerCase() == 'fa' || Inputs[i].lang.toLowerCase() == 'fa-ir')) {
            FarsiType.counter++;
            new FarsiType.KeyObject(Inputs[i], FarsiType.counter);
        }
    }

    var Areas = document.getElementsByTagName('TEXTAREA');
    for (var i=0; i<Areas.length; i++) {
        if (Areas[i].lang.toLowerCase() == 'fa' || Areas[i].lang.toLowerCase() == 'fa-ir') {
            FarsiType.counter++;
            new FarsiType.KeyObject(Areas[i], FarsiType.counter);
        }
    }
    
    var Dis = document.getElementById('disableFarsiType')
    if (Dis != null) {
        FarsiType.enable_disable (Dis);
        Dis.onclick = new Function( "FarsiType.enable_disable (this);" )
    }
}

FarsiType.KeyObject = function(z,x) {

    GenerateStr = "";
    if (FarsiType.ShowChangeLangButton == 1) {
        GenerateStr = GenerateStr + "<input type='button' id=FarsiType_button_"+x+" style='border: none; background-color:darkblue; font-size:11; color:white; font-family:tahoma; padding: 1px; margin: 1px; width: auto; height: auto;' value='FA' />&nbsp;";
    }
    if (FarsiType.ChangeDir == 2) {
        GenerateStr = GenerateStr  + "<input type='button' id=FarsiType_ChangeDir_"+x+" style='border: none; background-color:darkblue; font-size:11; color:white; font-family:tahoma; padding: 1px; margin: 1px; width: auto; height: auto;' value='RTL' />"
    }
    z.insertAdjacentHTML("afterEnd", GenerateStr);

    if (FarsiType.ShowChangeLangButton == 1) { 
        z.bottelm = document.getElementById ('FarsiType_button_' + x);
        z.bottelm.title = 'Change lang to english';
    }
    if (FarsiType.ChangeDir == 2) {
        z.Direlm = document.getElementById ('FarsiType_ChangeDir_' + x); 
    }

    z.farsi = true;
    z.dir = "rtl";
    z.align = "right";

    z.style.textAlign = z.align;
    z.style.direction = z.dir;

    setSelectionRange = function(input, selectionStart, selectionEnd) {
        input.focus()
        input.setSelectionRange(selectionStart, selectionEnd)
    }

    ChangeDirection = function() {
        if (z.dir == "rtl") {
            z.dir = "ltr";
            z.align = "left";
            z.Direlm.value = "LTR";
            z.Direlm.title = "Change direction: Right to Left"
        } else {
            z.dir = "rtl";
            z.align = "right";
            z.Direlm.value = "RTL";
            z.Direlm.title = "Change direction: Left to Right"
        }
        z.style.textAlign = z.align;
        z.style.direction = z.dir;
        z.focus();
    }

    ChangeLang = function(e, ze) {
        if(ze)
            z = ze;

        if (FarsiType.Type) {
            if (z.farsi) {
                z.farsi = false;
                if (FarsiType.ShowChangeLangButton == 1) { 
                    z.bottelm.value = "EN";
                    z.bottelm.title = 'Change lang to persian';
                }
                if (FarsiType.ChangeDir == 1) {
                    z.style.textAlign = "left";
                    z.style.direction = "ltr";
                }
            } else {
                z.farsi = true;
                if (FarsiType.ShowChangeLangButton == 1) { 
                    z.bottelm.value = "FA";
                    z.bottelm.title = 'Change lang to english';
                }
                if (FarsiType.ChangeDir == 1) {
                    z.style.textAlign = "right";
                    z.style.direction = "rtl";
                }
            }
            z.focus();
        }
        
        if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
        e.returnValue = false;
        return false;
    }

    Convert = function(e) {

        if (e == null)
            e = window.event;

        var key = e.which || e.charCode || e.keyCode;
        var eElement = e.target || e.originalTarget || e.srcElement;

        if (e.ctrlKey && key == 32) {
            ChangeLang(e, z);
        }

        if (FarsiType.Type) {
            if (
                (e.charCode != null && e.charCode != key) ||
                (e.which != null && e.which != key) ||
                (e.ctrlKey || e.altKey || e.metaKey) ||
                (key == 13 || key == 27 || key == 8)
            ) return true;

            //check windows lang
            if (key > 128) {
                if (FarsiType.KeyBoardError == 0) {
                    FarsiType.Disable();
                } else {
                    alert("Please change your windows language to English");
                    return false;
                }
            }

            // If Farsi
            if (FarsiType.Type && z.farsi) {

                //check CpasLock
                if ((key >= 65 && key <= 90&& !e.shiftKey) || (key >= 97 && key <= 122 ) && e.shiftKey) {
                    alert("Caps Lock is On. To prevent entering farsi incorrectly, you should press Caps Lock to turn it off.");
                    return false;
                }

                // Shift-space -> ZWNJ
                if (key == 32 && e.shiftKey)
                    key = 8204;
                else
                    key = FarsiType.farsiKey[key-32];

                key = typeof key == 'string' ? key : String.fromCharCode(key);

                // to farsi
                try {
                
                    var docSelection = document.selection;
                    var selectionStart = eElement.selectionStart;
                    var selectionEnd = eElement.selectionEnd;

                    if (typeof selectionStart == 'number') { 
                        //FOR W3C STANDARD BROWSERS
                        var nScrollTop = eElement.scrollTop;
                        var nScrollLeft = eElement.scrollLeft;
                        var nScrollWidth = eElement.scrollWidth;
    
                        eElement.value = eElement.value.substring(0, selectionStart) + key + eElement.value.substring(selectionEnd);
                        setSelectionRange(eElement, selectionStart + key.length, selectionStart + key.length);
        
                        var nW = eElement.scrollWidth - nScrollWidth;
                        if (eElement.scrollTop == 0) { eElement.scrollTop = nScrollTop }
                    } else if (docSelection) {
                        var nRange = docSelection.createRange();
                        nRange.text = key;
                        nRange.setEndPoint('StartToEnd', nRange);
                        nRange.select();
                    }
    
                } catch(error) {
                    try {
                        // IE
                        e.keyCode = key
                    } catch(error) {
                        try {
                            // OLD GECKO
                            e.initKeyEvent("keypress", true, true, document.defaultView, false, false, true, false, 0, key, eElement);
                        } catch(error) {
                            //OTHERWISE
                            if (FarsiType.UnSupportedAction == 0) {
                                alert('Sorry! no FarsiType support')
                                FarsiType.Disable();
                                var Dis = document.getElementById('disableFarsiType')
                                if (Dis != null) {
                                    Dis.disabled = true;
                                }
                                return false;
                            } else {
                                eElement.value += key;                  
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (e.preventDefault)
                    e.preventDefault();
                e.returnValue = false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    if (FarsiType.ShowChangeLangButton == 1) { z.bottelm.onmouseup = ChangeLang; }
    if (FarsiType.ChangeDir == 2) { z.Direlm.onmouseup = ChangeDirection; }
    z.onkeypress = Convert;
}

if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent('onload', FarsiType.init)
} else if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('load', FarsiType.init, false)
}
```